# How this logging way can be corrected

Tags: python, logging

My logging module: `MyLog.py`

```
import logging

class MyLogC(logging.Filterer):
      def __init__(self):
          self.myLogger = logging.getLogger('')
          self.myLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
          self.myLogFile = logging.FileHandler("./ex.log","w")
          self.myLogger.addHandler(self.myLogFile)
          self.myLogFormatter= logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
          self.myLogFile.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
          self.myLogFile.setFormatter(self.myLogFormatter)


      def MyLogger(self):
          return self.myLogger
```

In other module: `MyTh.py`

```
import MyLog

class MyThread(threading.Thread):

      def __init__(self,name,value):
          threading.Thread.__init__(self,None,MyClient,name,(),None,None)
          ...
          self.logger=MyLog.MyLogC.MyLogger


      def run(self):
          ...
          self.logger.info("abc")
```

and using

```
self.logger=MyLog.MyLogC.MyLogger
```

But I am getting ('function' object has no attribute 'info') error while using:

```
self.logger.info("abc")
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting `self.logger` to be a logger instance, but currently `MyLog.MyLogC` is a class, and the `MyLogger` is a method on that class.

Try `self.logger = MyLog.MyLogC().MyLogger()` (note the parens).

This first creates a `MyLogC` object, then invokes the `MyLogger` method on it to get the actual logger instance.

Comment: How can it be done , when i want to use the same logger instance in all other modules yet to implement. by MyLog.MyLogC(), we are creating new instances everytime ..right ?

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap the logging module? Usually doing this is just a sign that you don't understand how to use it properly. However, you'll obviously need a global variable somewhere if you want to share things.

Comment: Thanks . missing the basics :-)